# Gmail(google) password

Tags: gmail, password, google

I'm **logged in** on my android tablet, but **I don't** know my **password**.
I'm already logged in on my android tablet, but I want to see my emails and other google services **on PC**...
Is there possible way to find my pass on tablet?
I have already tried with "Password forget?", but I don't have alternative email or mobile nummber (on my account, at all), so I can't pass 2nd step of verification.

Answer (score 2):

You can reset the password using Google password recovery. Go here - [Account recovery](https://www.google.com/accounts/recovery/).
Follow on-screen instructions:

- Select I don't know my password. Type your email address.
- It asks for any previous password you remember (if there is one). Type password & continue.
- Next screen will be like this - **Confirm password reset on my Android XXYYZZ phone**. Select Send Notification.
- Follow on-screen instructions afterwards.

Edit 1:

- If you don't have access to your mobile device and do not have an alternate email ID, you can still recover/reset password by answering some questions on recovery page. You need to follow on-screen instructions carefully to reach that page.

Comment: My phone doesn't prompt for a new password after accepting the password reset. There's just a brief pop-up saying that the request was accepted.